# ui5plugin-linter: "sap.suite.ui.commons" Timeline class doesn't exist

Tags: sapui5

I try using Timeline control from the "sap.suite.ui.commons" library within Visual Studio Code, but the [TagLinter (UI5plugin)](https://github.com/iljapostnovs/ui5plugin-linter) shows this error:

> "sap.suite.ui.commons.Timeline" class doesn't exist

[image: Error in visual studio code]

[image: Class error]

Comment: If you plan to continue using the `ui5plugin-linter`, consider asking the maintainer about this issue at https://github.com/iljapostnovs/ui5plugin-linter/issues since the linter is a 3rd party package from the community. You might have something missing in the linter configuration.

Answer (score -2):

Done, the solution with sap.ui.core.HTML

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So you spent 2 days reinventing the wheel because your VSCode plugin doesn't recognize the Timeline control?

Comment: Yes Marc, i couldn't do it with the standard library